# Rails refactor/combine similar before_update callback methods into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, callback

I’ve created some model callback methods that timestamp an attribute every time a file is created, changed or removed.

I was wondering whether there was a more elegant way to write these callbacks, without having to repeat similar method code five times:

```
before_update :quote_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.quote_file_changed? }
before_update :survey_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.survey_file_changed? }
before_update :sign_off_sheet_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.sign_off_sheet_file_changed? }
before_update :invoice_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.invoice_file_changed? }
before_update :cert_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.cert_file_changed? }


def quote_file_updated?
  self.remove_quote_file ? self.quote_file_date = nil : self.quote_file_date = Time.now
end

def survey_file_updated?
  self.remove_survey_file ? self.survey_file_date = nil : self.survey_file_date = Time.now
end

def sign_off_sheet_file_updated?
  self.remove_sign_off_sheet_file ? self.sign_off_sheet_file_date = nil : self.sign_off_sheet_file_date = Time.now
end

def invoice_file_updated?
  self.remove_invoice_file ? self.invoice_file_date = nil : self.invoice_file_date = Time.now
end

def cert_file_updated?
  self.remove_cert_file ? self.cert_file_date = nil : self.cert_file_date = Time.now
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s better to keep the code verbose in this case, as it’s hard to see what’s going on. The callbacks should be changed so that the `before_update` becomes `before_save` (so it’s fired on the create action too).

The callback should be:

```
before_save :quote_file_updated?, if: ->(r) { r.quote_file_changed? or r.remove_quote_file.to_b }
```

The `to_b` is a method that converts the `0` or `1` from the `remove_quote_file` to a boolean. Based on this we can set the datestamp to `nil` when the file is removed.

The method itself should then become:

```
def quote_file_updated?
  remove_quote_file.to_b ? self.quote_file_date = nil : self.quote_file_date = Time.now
end
```

We do a similar thing again evaluating the `remove_quote_file` as a boolean and then updating or removing the timestamp based on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
before_update :set_updated_fields, on: [:create, :update]

def set_updated_fields
  ["quote", "survey", "sign_off_sheet", "invoice", "cert"].each do |filetype|
    if self.send("#{filetype}_file_changed?")
      self.attributes = {"#{filetype}_file_date" => self.send("remove_#{filetype}_file") ? nil : Time.now}
    end
  end
end
```

This is a bit incomprehensible but i think it will work.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original code where `quote_file_changed?` was repeated for each callback. Sorry about that, it’s updated now. How might I refactor your answer to reflect the change?

Comment: Ok, hang on.  I take it they're meant to be `survey_file.changed?`, `sign_off_sheet_file_changed?` etc?

Comment: Thanks! It’s working perfectly when I create and remove the file, but not when I update the file with a new value.

Comment: Put some logging in to have a look at the associated file (which we're testing with `"#{filetype}_file_changed?".  Sometimes with proxy associations the object can have an associated object in memory and not "notice" that it's changed in the database.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Will investigate and post up the answer when I’ve got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also bear in mind "order effects" - eg, if the changes made to the quote_file happen after the changes to the object in question here.  If you're changing both with the same form submission, for example, then check things are being done in the right order.  There's probably a less fragile way to arrange this but i can't say what since i'm not familiar with your code.

Comment: Would you recommend keeping the code verbose in this case? I’m still having trouble getting it working using the refactored version.

Comment: Well, it will be good for you to figure out why it's not working and fix it - step through it in the console. Re the verbosity, I personally wouldn't do something like my solution in my job because I know my colleagues would see it and say "what the hell is happening there?". Readability is important.

Comment: I solved it! Solution was to change `before_update` to `before_save` (so it gets fired on the create action too), and then edit the callback to `before_save :survey_file_updated?, if: ->(r) { r.survey_file_changed? or r.remove_survey_file.to_b }` (the `to_b` converting the `0` or `1` to boolean, to evaluate whether the file is being removed or not. And then in the callback method do a similar thing again `remove_quote_file.to_b ? self.quote_file_date = nil : self.quote_file_date = Time.now`. There’s probably a better way but this seems to work well.